# Extracting pattern from raw string

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract latitude and longitude from a raw dataset. The information I am interested in follows always the same pattern, namely:

> ```
> (,)(0-9)([.])(0-9) space (0-9)([.])(0-9)(,)
> ```

When I do the following, I am able to remove exactly the information I want to keep. Is there a way to do the inverse and actually keep the information I am removing at the moment using gsub?

```
data$l1<-gsub('(,)([0-9]+)([.])([0-9]+)[ ]([0-9]+)([.])([0-9]+)(,)', 
              '\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7',
              data$V1)
```

The dataset looks something like this:

```
V1
60346241,[37.55 55.22 5km],katekin,55.745011917 37.604520766,2013-12-04 11:59:07
603423423,[37.55 55.22 5km],#hello,#yes,miguel,53.23452 38.7379422,2013-12-04 11:49:09
```

So, in this example I would like to generate a new variable V2, that would be

```
V2
55.745011917 37.604520766
53.23452 38.7379422
```

Comment: Are the latitude and longitude always followed by a date?

Comment: Hmmm, yes. I think so. Big dataset, but it seems so.

Comment: `gsub('.*,((-?\\d+\\.\\d+ ?){2}),.*', '\\1', d$V1)`

Comment: @alistaire nice one.  why the `-?`?

Comment: @Jota Latitude and longitude can be negative. I'm not sure they are here, but if anybody else is going to try to adapt the answer, it's safer.

Comment: @alistaire got it.  I took OP's lead and assumed no negative values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `gregexpr` and `regmatches`

```
regmatches(d$V1, gregexpr("(?<=,)\\d{1,3}\\.\\d+\\s\\d{1,3}\\.\\d+", d$V1, perl = TRUE))

#[[1]]
#[1] "55.745011917 37.604520766"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "53.23452 38.7379422"
```

Unlisting it and putting it in a new variable is left up to the asker.

The approach here is to look for 1 to 3 digits followed by a decimal (`\\d{1,3}\\.`) followed by some digits and a space (`\\d+\\s`), then repeat, except without the trailing space.  The whole thing should be preceded by a comma.  So, you can use a lookbehind for the comma (i.e. `(?<=,)`)

---

You could use `gsub`, though with a couple of slight modifications:

```
gsub("^.+?(?<=,)(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d+\\s\\d{1,3}\\.\\d+).+$", "\\1", d$V1, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "55.745011917 37.604520766" "53.23452 38.7379422"
```

With the `gsub` approach, I use a capture group to capture the part I want: `(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d+\\s\\d{1,3}\\.\\d+)`, but I also match everything from the start of the line up to what I want to capture: `^.+?(?<=,)` and everything after it until the end of the line: `.+$`

---

Data:

```
d <- read.table(text = "V1
60346241,[37.55 55.22 5km],katekin,55.745011917 37.604520766,2013-12-04 11:59:07
603423423,[37.55 55.22 5km],#hello,#yes,miguel,53.23452 38.7379422,2013-12-04 11:49:09", header = TRUE, comment.char = "", sep = "\t")
```

Comment: Thanks! Used gsub method you recommended, worked perfect.